# Python multicast network unreachable with static IP

Tags: python, pi-4

i have encountered the following problem on a Raspberry PI4 B. I have a python program which communicates with PLCs. I run this program on my Windows machine with no problems. The program, after communication, multicasts an RFID reader's input to the address 239.192.1.X. In order to be able to communicate with the PLC i have to set static IP addresses, and works fine if the Raspberry's IP is not static. Static IP addresses:

PLC: 192.168.250.1

Rasp: 192.168.250.10

PC: 192.168.250.2

I observe the communication between the two on the PC running Wireshark. The problem is that when I try to multicast with my python program to the address 239.192.1.X, i get ERROR 101: Network Unreachable in python. The program works with direct UDP packages (e.g. sent to the PC or the PLC direclty), only gets error when I try to multicast(which is needed for correct communication between the Raspberry and the PLC and my project).

relevant (simplified) python code:

```
udp_port = 2222
udp_client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
udp_client.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_TTL, 32)
udp_multicast_group = '239.192.1.64'
data = b'123 multicast'
while True:
    udp_client.sendto(data, (udp_multicast_group, udp_port))
```

thank you for your help

Comment: Thank you for giving me a reason to look up PLC and reread about multicast.  I believe that "network unreachable" means the IP routing tables don't have an entry that tells it how to send traffic to 239.192.164.  Also, is everything a 24-bit subnet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, check that multicast is enabled on the target interface with `ip addr show`. You should also check if you have `CONFIG_IP_MULTICAST=y` set in the kernel, which is the case if you use Raspbian.

Then try joining a multicast address with e.g.

```
sudo ip addr add 239.192.1.64/24 dev eth0 autojoin
```

Check that the new multicast address shows up with

```
ip -f inet maddr show dev eth0
```

Note that if you want to use `ping` to test multicast IPv4 addresses, you will also need

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts=0
```

Comment: thank you, 
`sudo ip addr add 239.192.1.64/24 dev eth0 autojoin`
fixed it instantly!